# Find max and min values and its corresponding insert time from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where multiple records insert each day. Now I want to select the max and min value of each day of a given month and their respective inserted DateTime in a single query.

Table Schema

```
DtTime   datetime
Value1   decimal(18,2)
```

Sample Data

```
DtTime                    Value1    
--------------------------------    
2020-01-09 22:29:17.000    0.00
2020-01-09 22:30:41.000    0.40
2020-01-09 22:33:58.000    0.10
2020-01-09 22:34:59.000    2.49
2020-01-09 22:35:40.000    0.00
2020-01-10 00:33:07.000    0.10
2020-01-10 00:34:34.000    2.69
2020-01-10 00:37:06.000    2.67
2020-01-10 00:40:19.000    2.52
2020-01-15 08:34:34.000    0.69
2020-01-15 11:37:06.000    6.67
2020-01-15 04:40:19.000    2.52
```

Desired Output

```
Min     MinTime                   Max        MaxTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
0.00    2020-01-09 22:29:17.000   2.49      2020-01-09 22:34:59.000
0.10    2020-01-10 00:33:07.000   2.69      2020-01-10 00:34:34.000
0.69    2020-01-15 08:34:34.000   6.67      2020-01-15 11:37:06.000
```

similarly for all days of a given month and if the record doesn't exist for a day then it will show 0 in all fields.

Comment: can you add the schemas and/or sample data and corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `group by` or `Over with partition by`. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e82fc3b1b24ec1cef774a87ff4020e9)

```
 Select min(Value1) as minId
          , min(DtTime) as MinDtTime
          , max(Value1) as maxId
          , max(DtTime) as MaxDtTime
    from YourTable
    group by Cast( DtTime as Date)
```

OR

```
Select distinct
     min(Value1) OVER (PARTITION BY Cast( DtTime as Date) ) as minId
    , min(DtTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Cast( DtTime as Date)) as MinDtTime
    , max(Value1) OVER (PARTITION BY Cast( DtTime as Date)) as maxId
    , max(DtTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Cast( DtTime as Date)) as MaxDtTime
from YourTable
```

Comment: The output is slightly different from what OP wanted to see he want `2020-01-10 00:34:34.000` but in the output, it is coming `2020-01-10 00:40:19.000` for the second row.

Comment: It selects first inserted datetime as min time and last record as max time of each day instead of corresponding datetime of values.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the data you require;

```
(SELECT
MinV,
DtTime
FROM
    (SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a1.DtTime,102) AS [Date],
        MIN(a1.Value1) AS 'MinV'
        FROM dbo.ValueEntries a1
        GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a1.DtTime,102)
    ) b1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        a2.DtTime, a2.Value1
    FROM dbo.ValueEntries a2) b2 ON b1.MinV = b2.Value1 AND b1.Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),b2.DtTime,102)
) 

(SELECT
MaxV,
DtTime
FROM
    (SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a1.DtTime,102) AS [Date],
        MAX(a1.Value1) AS 'MaxV'
        FROM dbo.ValueEntries a1
        GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a1.DtTime,102)
    ) b1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        a2.DtTime, a2.Value1
    FROM dbo.ValueEntries a2) b2 ON b1.MaxV = b2.Value1 AND b1.Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),b2.DtTime,102)
)
```

Outputs as follows;

```
MinV    DtTime
0.00    2020-01-09 22:29:17.000
0.00    2020-01-09 22:35:40.000
0.10    2020-01-10 00:33:07.000
0.69    2020-01-15 08:34:34.000

MaxV    DtTime
2.49    2020-01-09 22:34:59.000
2.69    2020-01-10 00:34:34.000
6.67    2020-01-15 11:37:06.000
```

Now depending on what you actually want to do with the data you can export this or feed it into a reporting dashboard.

However if you were looking at using this dynamically in a dashboard or application of some sort I would recommend that you construct the data into cubes, like the above, rather than attempt to output it all at once.

If you are looking to regular report on date by groups, then consider an additional column to make your life much more straight forward.

```
DtTime   datetime
DtSpec   date
Value1   decimal(18,2)
```

This will also no doubt make the execution much easier for your server.

Also, don't forget to use Primary keys in your tables, with this it makes explicit joins easier to manipulate your data, therefore your new schema should look more like this;

```
ID       INT(PK)
DtTime   datetime
DtSpec   date
Value1   decimal(18,2)
```

Hope this helps you understand better how to move forward.
Good luck!

Comment: It is selecting only one date field but I want Inserted time also with date for both minvalue inserted and maxvalue inserted.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have "first" and "last" aggregation functions.  But you can use window functions for this purpose:

```
select distinct cast(dttime as date) as dte,
       min(Value1) over (partition by cast( dttime as Date) ) as maxValue,
       first_value(dttime) over (partition by cast( dttime as Date) order by value1 asc) as min_time,
       max(Value1) over (partition by cast( dttime as Date) ) as maxValue,
       first_value(dttime) over (partition by cast( dttime as Date) order by value1 desc) as max_time
from t
order by dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1cacdd087ddbf54f189df3174c965cc4) is a db<>fiddle.